# Python: Multiple Search in same Text-File

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-files

I have a huge text-file, with data something like this :

```
Name : ABC  
Bank : Bank1    
Account-No : 01234567    
Amount: 123456    
Spouse : CDF    
Name : ABD    
Bank : Bank1    
Account-No : 01234568    
Amount: 12345    
Spouse : BDF    
Name : ABE    
Bank : Bank2    
Account-No : 01234569    
Amount: 12344    
Spouse : CDG    
.
.
.
.
.
```

I need to fetch `Account-No` and `Amount` and then write them to the new file

```
Account-No: 01234567
Amount    : 123456
Account-No: 01234568
Amount    : 12345
Account-No: 01234569
Amount    : 12344
.
.
.
```

I tried to search the text-file through `mmap` to get the position of Account-No, but I am not able
to get the next account-no through this.

```
import mmap
fname = input("Enter the file name")
f1 = open(fname)

s  = mmap.mmap(f1.fileno(),0,access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
if s.find(b'Account-No') != -1:
    r = s.find(b'Account-No')
f1.close()
```

In 'r' I have the first location of the Account-No, but I am not able to search from (r+1) to get
the next Account-No.

I can put this in loop, but the exact syntax for mmap is not working for me.

Can anyone please help me in this regard through mmap or any other method.

Comment: Try using regular expressions with `re.search`. You might want to use the multiline option as well

Comment: You could write your own parser to do so...

Comment: Could you just grep the file?

Answer (score 1):

With `pandas`, we can do the following:

```
import pandas as pd

rowsOfLines = pd.read_table('my_file.txt', header=None)

with open('output_file.txt', 'w+') as file:
    for index, row in rowsOfLines.iterrows():
        splitLine = row.str.split()[0]
        if 'Account-No' in splitLine:
            file.write('{} \n'.format(row.to_string(index=False)))
        elif 'Amount:' in splitLine:
            file.write('{} \n'.format(row.to_string(index=False)))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution for huge files:

Here is a working example that you can easily customize by adding or removing field names to the "required_fields" list.
This solution allows you to handle a massive file because the whole file in not read into memory at the same time.

```
import tempfile

# reproduce your input file
# for the purpose of having a
# working example
input_filename = None
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as f_orig:
    input_filename = f_orig.name
    f_orig.write("""Name : ABC

Bank : Bank1

Account-No : 01234567

Amout: 123456

Spouse : CDF

Name : ABD

Bank : Bank1

Account-No : 01234568

Amout: 12345

Spouse : BDF

Name : ABE

Bank : Bank2

Account-No : 01234569

Amout: 12344

Spouse : CDG""")
    # start looking from the beginning of the file again
    f_orig.seek(0)

    # list the fields you want to keep
    required_fields = [
        'Account-No',
        'Amout',
    ]

    # filter and write, line by line
    result_filename = None
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as f_result:
        result_filename = f_result.name
        # process one line at a time (memory efficient)
        while True:
            line = f_orig.readline()
            #check if we have reached the end of the file
            if not line:
                break
            for field_name in required_fields:
                # write fields of interest to new file
                if field_name in line:
                    f_result.write(line)
                    f_result.write('\n') # just for formatting


    # show result
    with open(result_filename, 'r') as f:
        print(f.read())
```

The result of this is:

```
Account-No : 01234567

Amout: 123456

Account-No : 01234568

Amout: 12345

Account-No : 01234569

Amout: 12344
```

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
listOfAllAccountsAndAmounts = [] # list to save all the account and lists
searchTexts = ['Account-No','Amout'] # what all you want to search

with open('a.txt', 'r') as inFile:
    allLines = inFile.readlines() # read all the lines
    # save all the indexes of those that have any of the words from the searchTexts list in them
    indexOfAccounts = [ i for i, line in enumerate(allLines) if any( x in line for x in searchTexts) ] 

    for index in indexOfAccounts:
        listOfAllAccountsAndAmounts.append(allLines[index][:-1].split(': '))

print(listOfAllAccountsAndAmounts)
```

Output:

```
[['Account-No ', '01234567'], ['Amout', '123456'], ['Account-No ', '01234568'], ['Amout', '12345'], ['Account-No ', '01234569'], ['Amout', '12344']]
```

If you don't want to split and save as it is:

```
listOfAllAccountsAndAmounts.append(allLines[index])
```

Output:

```
['Account-No : 01234567\n', 'Amout: 123456\n', 'Account-No : 01234568\n', 'Amout: 12345\n', 'Account-No : 01234569\n', 'Amout: 12344\n']
```

I have written to a list in case you want to process the information. You can also directly simply write the string to the new file without even using a list as shown by @Arda.

Answer (score -1):

Can You  read the whole text file and return will be the list,so iterate over the list and search for string "Account no." and "amount" in it and write over to the another file.